# Surface View in round shape on top of other surface view

Tags: android, video-streaming, surfaceview, agora.io

My requirement is to show video chat using surface view. And my video view will contain both remote view and local view as well.

I am able to round the shape of local surface view, but when remote video view get inflated then local surface view comes back to original rectangle shape.

I am using outline provide and clipping enabled to make round shape of surface view.

This is the snapshot I want to achieve.
[Local video surface view on top of other remote video surface view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um1u5.png)

And this is what I am getting:-

Before remote view get inflated with video:
[I can get curve shape of local view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWQKJ.png)

After remote view get inflated with video:
[again local view came back to original shape i.e rectangular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB86y.png)

This is my xml code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_video_chat_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="io.agora.tutorials1v1vcall.VideoChatViewActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/remote_video_view_container"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/remoteBackground">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/local_frame"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/local_preview_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/remote_video_view_container">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/local_video_view_container"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/local_preview_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/local_preview_height"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/local_preview_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/local_preview_margin_right"
            android:background="@color/localBackground"
            android:elevation="10dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here remote surface view will go inside the @+id/remote_video_view_container

and local surface view will go inside the @+id/local_video_view_container with circle in shape.

For more reference, I have taken this sample for 1 to 1 video chat.[sample video chat](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call)

NOTE:-  I can't create the custom surface view as surface view instance I am getting dynamically from 3rd party library.

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using AgoraTextureView for remote and SurfaceView for local. Sample project which I have built to showcase this: https://slack-files.com/T1CBEDLJY-F012R1T5CL8-7425620f71